# Magento Custom Options / Associated Products Order

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, xml

I have a configurable product which has associated simple products, but on the configurable there is also two custom options.

I would like the custom options to display first rather than the associated dropdown options.

By default custom options display after associated options list.

I saw a reference call in the XML which relates to the block

'product.info.options.wrapper'

However looking into how the option types are loaded, I cannot see how they are chosen to loaded in with an order without a position call.

Any advice would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local.xml you likely want to edit the product type configurable handle to `unset` the configurable options and then re-set them so that they're effectively appended to the bottom of the block. Something akin to the following (warning, untested code):

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.options.configurable</name></action>
        <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.configurable</block></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```